# Inputting Data from user in AndEngine Scene

Tags: android, andengine

I want to input data i.e.  name and age of user on a scene of AndEngine. How can I do that ??
I dont want to use a dialog for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked this on the AndEngine forums and RealMayo gave you the best answer there.

Study the TextBreakExample.java - and more specifically, study the AndEngineExamples/res/layout/textbreakexample.xml file

You will see how to "blend" a standard Android EditText (not a dialog) into your game.

Comment: unfortunately i couldn't find the example you specified pleas correct me if I am wrong. I am searching the file here

    https://github.com/devproof/andengineexamples/tree/65dcabe1982184cdd38e57ea369b65cf64a65289/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples

Comment: The src file is here https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/TextBreakExample.java The XML file is here https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/res/layout/textbreakexample.xml

Comment: that devproof repository is old and references the source from GoogleCode (I don't think that's been updated since Nicolas moved over to GitHub). IMHO, you should be using the source from Nicholas since he's guy that wrote AndEngine and he updates it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is a text entry overlay, you can add it in your onSetContentView() method:

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {
  editTextExample = new EditText(this);
  this.addContentView(editTextExample, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to make editable text whose look can be set by AndEngine, check out the example [Java code](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/TextBreakExample.java) and [XML code](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/res/layout/xmllayoutexample.xml)